# How to print HTML/PHP page without including the NAVIGATION TAB contents, FOOTER, and head part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to print HTML/PHP page without including the NAVIGATION TAB contents, FOOTER, and head part. I'm using plain HTML. I don't have CSS applied on it because of the purpose of printing...

I actually am using these codes:

```
<body onload='window.print(); window.close();'>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

for printing...

So in my page I have a link that says "Back" its a link where I have to back to the page where I was before going to this print page. When I am going to print, CTRL+P, the BACK link is included on printing. How can I hide it when printing?

Comment: I would suggest adding a media:print CSS-rule where you can then define, which elements should be visible vor invisible (display: none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS Print Media Queries

There are CSS media queries specifically for printed media.

### Example

```
@media print {
   header, footer, nav, aside {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

### [More information](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/08/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a **print css** by using `css media types`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print_style.css" media="print" />
```

and in that

```
.header,.footer,.navigation
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
        size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }
 .navigation,.footer,.header
        {
          display:none;
        }
</style>
```